# Chrome Drag & Drop triggering :hover pseudo-class on surrounding elements

Tags: css, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, hover, draggable

I'm running into very frustrating and unexpected drag and drop behavior in Chrome.

### Problem:

The `:hover` pseudo-class is triggered and stuck on surrounding elements, particularly ones where the DragElement's ghost is overlapping it.

**Steps to reproduce the issue:**

- **Example:** http://plnkr.co/edit/PayXodHUtxqUZsM3T2ye **then preview in Separate Window**
- Click and drag any of the number boxes.
- Drop it any of the other boxes with its ghost slightly overlapping surrounding elements.

This happens in Chrome 35, 36, and 38-beta. I also noticed this *isn't* happening in Plunker's Run frame with the editor, but is happening in the full windowed view (linked above). It also happens in my `node-webkit` app (where I discovered this problem).

### What I've tried so far:

- Using `-webkit-user-drag: element;` on `.box`
- Adding `draggable="true"` attribute on each `.box` element to see if there's a difference.
- `event.stopPropagation` on various elements, including `window`

Why would it be triggering `:hover` on the surrounding elements? It makes absolutely no sense. I'm about to rip my hair out! :/

Thanks in advance for anyone who is willing to help me solve this.

Comment: I've reported this to the Chromium Issues board, so I'm sure they're investigating this: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=410328

Comment: *I'm about to rip my hair out!*

Ha, I felt the same way trying to debug this.

Comment: Still an issue 2 years later!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered jQuery UI? I know the less external  resources the better, but jQuery UI detects when you are dragging, and then (as "The Reveller" said), you could add a class to body and specify

```
.bodyIsDragging{
   pointer-events: none
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a class to your html/body tag while dragging? If so you could potentially use

```
.is-dragging * {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

where .is-dragging is the class on your body/html
and then override on the element you are currently dragging.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with (in a ugly way):

CSS:

```
.is-dragging {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

JS: (on the "drop" event)

```
$('body').addClass('is-dragging');

if (event.clientY < separatorY)
    dragged.insertBefore(target);
else
    dragged.insertAfter(target);

setTimeout(function()
{
    $('body').removeClass('is-dragging');
}, 1);
```